# Next / Prev and looping/cycling entries instead of reaching the end of the selected results

Tags: entries, forloop, loop

Is there a way to be able to use `entry.getNext(params)` to return back to the first entry when you're viewing the last entry in the parameters?

With the result of looping/cycling through all entries and returning to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't a "next" sibling, `entry.getNext()` returns `null` – in which case you can use Twig's `default` filter to set an alternative value (i.e. your *first* entry).

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext|craft.entries.section('mySectionHandle').first() %}
```